# Php regex to replace a string like this: [youtube XXXXXXXXXXX]?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have inherited a website in wordpress and I want to change the shortcode related to youtube for all the old articles already written.

The old code is this:

```
[youtube XXXXXXXXXXX]
```

(of course XXXXXXXXXXX is variable)

I want the new code to be like this:

```
http://youtu.be/XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Can you help me create a regular expression in order to replace all the posts content?
Thank you!

Comment: `\[youtube ([^\]]+)\]` will be your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \[(youtube)\s*(\S+)\]
```

You can replace by

```
  http://youtu.be/$2
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/1

Comment: -1 - doesn't even try to make sure it only matches "youtube" codes.